# glScissor() call inside another glScissor()

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl

I'm using `glScissor()` in my application and it works properly, but I met a problem:
I have my `Window` object for which drawing area is specified by `glScissor()` and inside this area, I'm drawing my `ListView` object for which the drawing area should also be specified with `glScissor()` as I don't want to draw it all.

In a code I could represent it as:

```
Window::draw() 
{
   glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glScissor(x, y, width, height);
        // Draw some components...
        mListView.draw(); // mListView is an object of ListView type
   glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
}

ListView::draw()
{
  glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glScissor(x, y, width, height);
        // Draw a chosen part of ListView here
   glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
}
```

But of course in this situation enable/disable calls are wrong:

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
   glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
   glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```

If I remove those internal glEnable/glDisable calls (the ones in ListView), I would anyway end up with two glScissor() calls which also seems to be wrong.

## EDIT

I would like to somehow achieve both scissor effects, I mean - that Window should draw only in it's scissored area and internal ListView also only in it's scissored area.

As you can see in a picture, with red rectangle I have marked scissor area for `Window` which WORKS, and with a blue rectangle I marked an area on which I'd like to draw my `ListView`. That's why I was trying to use nested scissors, but I know it was useless. So basically my question is, what could be the best approach to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: An object with reference counts

Comment: @PlasmaHH Sorry, but I don't know what you mean. What object with reference counts has to do with my problem?

Comment: you have an object where you call your enable/disable on, and it counts how often you do that, and only on the first/last it calls enable/disable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since OpenGL is a state machine and the scissor rect, like any other state, is overwritten when calling `glScissor` the next time, you have to properly restore the window's scissor rect after drawing the list view. This can either be done by just letting the window manage it:

```
Window::draw() 
{
    // draw some components with their own scissors
    mListView.draw(); // mListView is an object of ListView type

    glScissor(x, y, width, height);
    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
        // draw other stuff using window's scissor
    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
}
```

But it might be more flexible to let the individual components restore the scissor state themselves, especially if used in such a hierarchical manner. For this you can either use the deprecated `glPush/PopAttrib` functions to save and restore the scissor rect:

```
ListView::draw()
{
    glPushAttrib(GL_SCISSOR_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glScissor(x, y, width, height);
        // Draw a chosen part of ListView here
    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glPopAttrib();
}
```

Or you save and restore the scissor state yourself:

```
ListView::draw()
{
    // save
    int rect[4];
    bool on = glIsEnabled(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_SCISSOR_BOX, rect);

    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glScissor(x, y, width, height);
        // Draw a chosen part of ListView here

    // restore
    glScissor(rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3]);
    if(!on)
        glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
}
```

This can of course be automated with a nice RAII wrapper, but that is free for you to excercise.

Comment: @Mosquito Well, in fact I find *sheu*'s approach much better and more flexible. I don't even take the fact into account, that listview's scissor might not be inside the enclosing window's.

Comment: This does not work in mine. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

**edited**: General case.

Every time you set the scissor state with `glScissor`, you set the scissor state.  It does not nest, and it does not stack, so you cannot "subscissor" with nested calls to `glScissor`.  You'll have to manually compute the rectangular intersection of your `ListView` and your `Window` bounding rects, and then scissor to that when drawing `ListView`.

In the general case, you'll be manually maintaining a stack of scissor rectangles.  As you draw each sub-element, you intersect the sub-element's bounding rect against the current top of the stack, and use that as the scissor for that sub-element.  Push the new subrect onto the stack when painting children, and pop it when returning back up the hierarchy.

If you're painting other contents to `Window`, you'll also have to make sure to handle overdraw correctly; either by setting the Z ordering and enabling depth buffering, or by disabling depth buffering and painting your contents back-to-front.  Scissoring won't help you mask the `Window` contents behind the `ListView`, since scissors can only be rectangular regions.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is a state machine. You can call glScissor, glEnable and glDisable as often as you'd like to. They don't act like opening-closing braces that must be matched. If your calls "fold" like this, that's no problem. Just don't expect the one scissor to merge with the other one; it will merely change/overwrite the previous setting.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that's what I was afraid of in fact. :-) Maybe my question doesn't really explain this, but I would like to somehow achieve both scissor effects, I mean - that Window should draw only in it's scissored area and internal ListView also only in it's scissored area. I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Mosquito Isn't the listview always completely inside the window, anyway? In this case the internal (smaller) scissor of the listview should be sufficient. You just have to properly restore the (larger) scissor of the window after drawing the listview (so that following elements get rendered correctly). Other than that (if listview scissor could be larger that window scissor), just compute the intersecting rect of window and listview and use that as listview's scissor rect.

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes, you're right, restoring scissor of the window after drawing the listview should do the trick. :-) Is it possible to get current glScissor rect?

Comment: @Mosquito Well, you know it anyway, since you set it in the window drawing routine. But if you're lazy, you can also wrap the listview (and any other window's) drawing code inside a `glPushAttrib(GL_SCISSOR_BIT); ... glPopAttrib();` block. This saves and restores both the scissor rect and the enabled flag. But note that those functions are deprecated in modern (3+ core) GL. Otherwise, the current scissor rect can be obtained with a `glGetIntegerv(GL_SCISSOR_BOX, int_4_array);`. I'll write an answer, I think.

Comment: @Mosquito: The parameter to glScissor are in window coordinates. It's just a matter of a handfull min/max comparisions and some subtraction to "stack" them. I recommend you take a piece of paper and try to figure it out yourself. If you can't find the solution, I'll post some code.